# What does it mean by "follow a link" and "walk a tree"?

Tags: java

(I'm now a freshman to Java.)

Below are the text in Ivor Horton's Beginning Java

"To determine whether a Path object references a file or a directory, you can use the static isDirectory() and isRegularFile() methods in the Files class. With both methods the first argument is the Path object you are interested in. You can specify NOFOLLOW_LINKS as the optional second argument if you do not want **links to be followed**."

"The java.nio.file.FileVisitor interface specifies methods that you can use to **walk through a tree** of directories and files. T is the type of file reference, usually type Path. The java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor class implements the methods in the FileVisitor interface that simply visits all ﬁles in a tree and re-throws any I/O exceptions that occur."

Can anyone tell me what does it mean by "follow a link" and "walk a tree"? Please give me a code example if possible, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @JDein, I really don't understand your problem, could you please be more specific ?

Comment: I just cannot understand the two phrases ("links to be followed" and "walk through a tree")in the text. Could you tell me what these two phrases mean?

Answer (score 5):

"Follow a link" refers to following [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). You may want your program to not follow symbolic links (either for security reasons or other reasons), and so you can optionally prevent Java from following symbolic links

"Walk through a tree" refers to traversing the tree-like structure of the file system.  That is, there is a folder, and under that folder may be other folders, and under those folders may be more folders, etc.  If you drew a graph connecting a folder to its parent, you'd get a "tree" like structure (kinda like a family tree).  You may want to look at files recursively in your program (that is, look at the files in a folder, and then look at the files inside of the folders inside that folder, etc), and so Java allows you to do that by "walking through the directory tree."

Comment: Does it mean that hard link cannot be followed?

Comment: I am not 100% sure on that.  The [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html) only mention symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

Directory could have a link to another directory (esspecially common in Linux/Unix OS). Hence you can opt to follo or not follow this links.

The directory may have other directories underneath and those have yet more directories under them - this creates a tree of directories.